# How do I access the members in a stdClass array of stdClasses?

Tags: php, arrays, wsdl, soap-client, stdclass

I am wondering how I can access a stdObect array of stdObjects. I have an array that looks something like this when printing it with `print_r()`:

```
stdClass Object ([item] => Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object([id] => 0 [name] => Peter)
    [1] => stdClass Object([id] => 1 [name] => Jack)))
```

How can I access the name field? If it not was an array, I could get the attributes by calling the field, like:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://url.to.my.wsdl", array("trace" => 0));
echo $client->GetPerson()->name;
```

But when using arrays, this does not work:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://url.to.my.wsdl", array("trace" => 0));
$persons = $client->GetPersons();
echo $persons[0]->name;
```

That just gives me the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your print_r info ,just try

```
echo $persons->item[0]->name
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$persons->item[0]->name;
```

Comment: Thank you! Three equal answers from three different persons exactly the same time :-) I will give the "right answer" to the one with least reputation (@Lake). Hope that's ok :)

Answer (score 1):

The array is contained inside the field `item`.

```
echo $persons->item[0]->name;
```

Comment: Thank you! Three equal answers from three different persons exactly the same time :-) I will give the "right answer" to the one with least reputation (@Lake). Hope that´s ok :)